# Disposing faulted service channels on client side in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a WCF Websocket client server communication. What I want to do on client side, is to keep trying  to reconnect to the server, if server was shut down or something. From what I know, once a server is shut down, channel is in faulted state so I cannot use it again. I need to create a new one, but I am afraid, that there is memory leak in my solution:

creating the websocket service:

```
InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(this);
ServiceReference.SomeServiceClient client = new ServiceReference.MLogDbServiceClient(context);
```

reconnecting:

```
client.Abort();
client = new ServiceReference.MLogDbServiceClient(context);
```

In Windows Task Manager I  saw that in two minutes my app grew from 29mb to 48mb while I was keeping to create new channel every 20ms ( it was just for memory leak test purposes ).  Anyone has a leak-free solution for me? 
My client application NEEDS to keep reconnecting to the server (not so frequently but still). Greetings

Comment: Just because your memory usage went up does not mean you are leaking resources.  Did you run garbage collection? The Visual Studio diagnostics tools show a lot more information that can help you determine if you are in-fact leaking resources

Comment: No, I did not run Garbage Collection. But from what I have heard it is not recommended. Should I just wait for GC to clean things up? And how can i determine memory leak in visual studio? I know the process memory graph, but it is slowly increasing as well.

Comment: You are right that manually running GC is not recommended, it was just a question to see if it freed up some/all of the memory.  If it does, then you don't need to manually run it again, rather just wait for the GC to clean things up.  I think you are following the correct pattern, the only suggestion I would have is if the `ServiceClient` implements `IDisposable`, then you should call `Dispose` after `Abort`

Comment: I have just checked how it behaves with GC - some memory is freed, but not all of it. Application is still growing but considerably slower.

Comment: I think there is no leak after all. I changed frequency from 20 to 200ms and the app has stopped growing. 20ms was just too fast for some reason. Thanks for assistance :)